# Is Eclipse available for any Linux distro

Tags: linux, eclipse

All I see when I go to the Eclipse download page is 32bit and 64bit so just for windows. I'm new to Linux and would like to move gradually to it. Will I be able to use Eclipse on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux

Answer (score 3):

You might be accessing from a Windows machine. For Linux download [from here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux)

Answer (score 2):

you can install it from wither the package manager on your distro or from the command line using `sudo apt-get install eclipse` or `sudo yum install eclipse`, depending on whether your distro uses apt or yum.

Answer (score 1):

There's a dropdown where you can select alternate platforms - `http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux` when you select Linux from the list.